# Acer DustDefender and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers, acer, windows-10

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10 on my Acer V 17 Nitro.

This laptop comes with a functionality called "DustDefender" which is supposed to "prevents dust from accumulating inside the system".
DustDefender is working under Windows (there is an app dedicated to), but I want to make it work with Ubuntu.

So how can I do ?

Comment: DustDefender "works" by reversing the fan every few hours. The result is a loosening of the dust on the fan blades and blowing said dust back into the system. This is not a "feature" I would recommend.  Instead you should regularly blow the dust out of the system completely (preferably outdoors). Canned air works nicely for this. Since you are dual booting, if you feel that this feature is at all useful, just boot into Win 10 when you want to use it. I'm not personally convinced that it's remotely useful as even if the dust is evacuated from the system it will eventually get sucked back in.

Comment: Well, you are probably right, but at least for now I would like to consider that the feature is effective. 
Logging out from Ubuntu to boot into Windows every hour looks painful.

Comment: Research indicates that the feature is only designed to work every 3 hours if I'm not mistaken. Does your system intake enough dust that there's measurable output in that short period of time? I would think booting into windows before bed would be more than enough to provide what results the feature is capable of producing, overnight while you sleep. (I agree that booting into Windows and actually using it is painful)